# Optimizing Karatsuba Implementation

Tags: c#, biginteger

So, I'm trying to improve some of the operations that .net 4's `BigInteger` class provide since the operations appear to be quadratic. I've made a rough Karatsuba implementation but it's still slower than I'd expect.

The main problem seems to be that BigInteger provides no simple way to count the number of bits and, so, I have to use BigInteger.Log(..., 2). According to Visual Studio, about 80-90% of the time is spent calculating logarithms.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Numerics;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static BigInteger Karatsuba(BigInteger x, BigInteger y)
        {
            int n = (int)Math.Max(BigInteger.Log(x, 2), BigInteger.Log(y, 2));
            if (n <= 10000) return x * y;

            n = ((n+1) / 2);

            BigInteger b = x >> n;
            BigInteger a = x - (b << n);
            BigInteger d = y >> n;
            BigInteger c = y - (d << n);

            BigInteger ac = Karatsuba(a, c);
            BigInteger bd = Karatsuba(b, d);
            BigInteger abcd = Karatsuba(a+b, c+d);

            return ac + ((abcd - ac - bd) << n) + (bd << (2 * n));
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BigInteger x = BigInteger.One << 500000 - 1;
            BigInteger y = BigInteger.One << 600000 + 1;
            BigInteger z = 0, q;

            Console.WriteLine("Working...");
            DateTime t;

            // Test standard multiplication
            t = DateTime.Now;
            z = x * y;
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now - t);

            // Test Karatsuba multiplication
            t = DateTime.Now;
            q = Karatsuba(x, y);
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now - t);

            // Check they're equal
            Console.WriteLine(z == q);

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

So, what can I do to speed it up?

Comment: Could you give some context on what Karatsuba is?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help but maybe you can somehow cast it to a BitArray so that you can count the bits.

Comment: @aaronls: That is a lot faster, thanks.

Comment: @Chris: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm

Comment: `<<` has a lower precedence than `+`/`-`

Answer (score 13):

Why count all of the bits?

In vb I do this:

```
<Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Function BitLength(ByVal n As BigInteger) As Integer
    Dim Data() As Byte = n.ToByteArray
    Dim result As Integer = (Data.Length - 1) * 8
    Dim Msb As Byte = Data(Data.Length - 1)
    While Msb
        result += 1
        Msb >>= 1
    End While
    Return result
End Function
```

In C# it would be:

```
public static int BitLength(this BigInteger n)
{
    byte[] Data = n.ToByteArray();
    int result = (Data.Length - 1) * 8;
    byte Msb = Data[Data.Length - 1];
    while (Msb != 0) {
        result += 1;
        Msb >>= 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Finally...

```
    static BigInteger Karatsuba(BigInteger x, BigInteger y)
    {
        int n = (int)Math.Max(x.BitLength(), y.BitLength());
        if (n <= 10000) return x * y;

        n = ((n+1) / 2);

        BigInteger b = x >> n;
        BigInteger a = x - (b << n);
        BigInteger d = y >> n;
        BigInteger c = y - (d << n);

        BigInteger ac = Karatsuba(a, c);
        BigInteger bd = Karatsuba(b, d);
        BigInteger abcd = Karatsuba(a+b, c+d);

        return ac + ((abcd - ac - bd) << n) + (bd << (2 * n));
    }
```

Calling the extension method may slow things down so perhaps this would be faster:

```
int n = (int)Math.Max(BitLength(x), BitLength(y));
```

FYI: with the bit length method you can also calculate a good approximation of the log much faster than the BigInteger Method.

```
bits = BitLength(a) - 1;
log_a = (double)i * log(2.0);
```

As far as accessing the internal UInt32 Array of the BigInteger structure, here is a hack for that.

import the reflection namespace

```
Private Shared ArrM As MethodInfo
Private Shard Bits As FieldInfo
Shared Sub New()
    ArrM = GetType(System.Numerics.BigInteger).GetMethod("ToUInt32Array", BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance)
    Bits = GetType(System.Numerics.BigInteger).GetMember("_bits", BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance)(0)

End Sub
<Extension()> _
Public Function ToUInt32Array(ByVal Value As System.Numerics.BigInteger) As UInteger()
    Dim Result() As UInteger = ArrM.Invoke(Value, Nothing)
    If Result(Result.Length - 1) = 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve Result(Result.Length - 2)
    End If
    Return Result
End Function
```

Then you can get the underlying UInteger() of the big integer as

```
 Dim Data() As UInteger = ToUInt32Array(Value)
 Length = Data.Length
```

or Alternately

```
Dim Data() As UInteger = Value.ToUInt32Array()
```

Note that _bits fieldinfo can be used to directly access the underlying UInteger() _bits field of the BigInteger structure. This is faster than invoking the ToUInt32Array() method. However, when BigInteger B <= UInteger.MaxValue _bits is nothing. I suspect that as an optimization when a BigInteger fits the size of a 32 bit (machine size) word MS returns performs normal machine word arithmetic using the native data type.

I have also not been able to use the _bits.SetValue(B, Data()) as you normally would be able to using reflection. To work around this I use the BigInteger(bytes() b) constructor which has overhead. In c# you can use unsafe pointer operations to cast a UInteger() to Byte(). Since there are no pointer ops in VB, I use Buffer.BlockCopy. When access the data this way it is important to note that if the MSB of the bytes() array is set, MS interprets it as a Negative number. I would prefer they made a constructor with a separate sign field. The word array is to add an addition 0 byte to make uncheck the MSB

Also, when squaring you can improve even further

```
 Function KaratsubaSquare(ByVal x As BigInteger)
    Dim n As Integer = BitLength(x) 'Math.Max(BitLength(x), BitLength(y))

    If (n <= KaraCutoff) Then Return x * x
    n = ((n + 1) >> 1)

    Dim b As BigInteger = x >> n
    Dim a As BigInteger = x - (b << n)
    Dim ac As BigInteger = KaratsubaSquare(a)
    Dim bd As BigInteger = KaratsubaSquare(b)
    Dim c As BigInteger = Karatsuba(a, b)
    Return ac + (c << (n + 1)) + (bd << (2 * n))

End Function
```

This eliminates 2 shifts, 2 additions and 3 subtractions from each recursion of your multiplication algorithm.

Comment: Magnificent work Alexander Higgins! +1 for your answer which helped me in my search for perfect numbers...

Comment: Fascinating, but from a brief microbenchmark it seems .Net already uses this optimization; timings are close, with this sometimes being a bit faster, but on average (without doing the math) the default implementation seems to win by a narrow margin.

Comment: In practice there is a cutoff after which "grade school" loses to "Karatsuba" due to the 4/3 improvement. This is due to the algorithm overhead http://www.cburch.com/proj/karat/results.html. There are also other fast multiplication methods, such as Toom-Cook which is 9/5 improvement over "grade school" but in practice Karatsuba will win out up to some cutoff due to overhead. Likewise, there is a cutoff in the range of several thousands of digits where Fast Fourier beats out Toom-Cook.